# How can you get a plane with a emission node to be brighter in the center?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

How can I make a plane emit more light from the center using an emission node?
On this image here made with Cinima 4d The orange and blue planes are emitting more light from the center:

[image]

How can I acheve this effect in blender with cycles?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a material effect. Just put a lamp there and make it subtle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Material

You can use a *Gradient node* with *Object mapping* to make a spherical gradient based on the location of the object origin:

[image]

The mapping node is just used to scale the texture up a bit.
The multiply node controls the overall strength.

Note that scaling in object mode will stretch the texture accordingly, however applying the scale or scaling in edit mode will not.

## AO

It's also possible that your reference image was created with a very heavy *Ambient Occlusion* effect.

To achieve this:

1. Enable *AO* in *Properties > Render layers > Passes*
2. Adjust it and multiply it with the combined pass in the compositor:

   [image]

Combined with the gradient:

[image]

Comment: That works great but how would you spread out the light using the material method? Scaling up has no effect on the light.

Comment: You can manually compensate with the mapping node scale, but it should be stretching automatically.. Are you scaling in object mode?

Comment: I was scaling in edit mode

Comment: Using object mode worked